# Why does my text-align & vertical-align not work with an image?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm new here, and also new to HTML :D

Just faced a problem, and found that Stackoverflow had lots of amazing developers, so I'm throwing my problem here, and waiting for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Cafe</title>
    <style>
    #container {
        width:550px;
        height:733px;
        position:relative;
    }

    img#containerImage {
        position:absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    h1#header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        font-size:24px;
        font-weight:bold;
        border:1px solid red;
        margin: 0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img id="containerImage" src="olgagonggam.jpg"/>
        <h1 id="header">Cafe</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I've coded. I'm wondering why is the text not set middle/center, and how to fix this problem? The text is shown on the left top of the page, but I want to set it on the center of the image. Anyone please help me! :D

Comment: It's because you're using absolute position.

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal Is there any ways to do it with absolute position?

Comment: set the value of top left where you want. Use developer tool.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Thanks, so there's no way to align with absolute position, right?

Comment: see answer below if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the image is known (the question doesn't make that entirely clear) and the size of the h1 also is known, you can simply specify the location in pixels. In this case, position the left side at half the image width (275px) minus half the width of the h1 (30px) and the top at half the image height (367px) minus half the height of the h1 (15px).

```css
#container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 733px;
  position: relative;
}
img#containerImage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
h1#header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 245px;
  top: 352px;
  width: 60px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="containerImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/550/733" />
  <h1 id="header">Cafe</h1>
</div>
```

If you don't want to hard-code the sizes in pixels, it gets trickier. I came up with this solution, but it doesn't have the border around the h1.

```css
#container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 733px;
  position: relative;
}
img#containerImage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
h1#header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%; left:0; width:100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px; line-height:0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="containerImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/550/733" />
  <h1 id="header">Cafe</h1>
</div>
```